# Saving multiple figures in same pdf by iterating over variables - Python

Tags: python, pdfpages

How do I use pp.savefig() properly to iterate over multiple variables?

Instead of saving each figure one by one and adding them to the pdf

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
pp = PdfPages('data_report.pdf')

pp.savefig(shop_recovered_volume_graph)
pp.savefig(shop_recovered_cases_graph)
#etc...
pp.close()
```

I would like to loop over the saved variables in globals() which have the string '_graph' in them. My solution

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
pp = PdfPages('data_report.pdf')

#search for string
s = '_graph'

for i in globals():
    if s in i:
        print(i)
        pp.savefig(i)
pp.close()
```

prints the variables, but also gives ValueError: No such figure: 'shop_recovered_volume_graph' and does not save the figures. If savefig is empty, like pp.savefig(), only the last graph is saved multiple times in the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the following solution: The issue was accessing globals() correctly, which is a dictionary. So for a certain key I'm accessing the value:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

pp = PdfPages('data_report_graphs.pdf')

#search for string
string = '_graph'

globals_dict = globals()

for name, variable in globals_dict.items():
    if string in name:
        print(name)
        pp.savefig(variable)
pp.close()
```